# Process multiple directories in spark separately

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have got a list of directories in HDFS each containing several files. My goal is to merge all files from one directory into only one file but for each directory separately. What is the fastest way to do this in spark? Sequentially iterating over all directories is too slow. So I want to do it in parallel. One solution might be to use a thread pool. Maybe there is a better and faster more native one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following test directories `foo` and `bar` that contains the following files:

```
cat /tmp/foo/0.csv
4
cat /tmp/foo/1.csv
3
cat /tmp/bar/0.csv
7
```

We can read them using the following snippet:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("/tmp/foo", "/tmp/bar")
  .withColumn("dir", regexp_extract(input_file_name(), """([^/]*)/[^/]+\.csv$""", 1))
df.show()
/*
+---+---+
|_c0|dir|
+---+---+
|4  |foo|
|3  |foo|
|7  |bar|
+---+---+
*/
```

Function `input_file_name` gives the absolute path of the file so we can use that to get the directory. Function `regexp_extract` is used just to convert e.g `/tmp/foo/1.csv -> foo`.

When Spark writes files, it outputs one file per partition. Thus, we need to repartition by column `dir` to merge all files under each dir. Finally, we can use `partitionBy` to get the directory name to the output file structure as well. For example

```
df.repartition($"dir")
  .write
  .partitionBy("dir")
  .csv("/tmp/out")
```

would produce files

```
/tmp/out/._SUCCESS.crc
/tmp/out/dir=bar/.part-00067-d780b550-785f-416c-b090-8d93694ba65c.c000.csv.crc
/tmp/out/dir=bar/part-00067-d780b550-785f-416c-b090-8d93694ba65c.c000.csv
/tmp/out/_SUCCESS
/tmp/out/dir=foo/part-00110-d780b550-785f-416c-b090-8d93694ba65c.c000.csv
/tmp/out/dir=foo/.part-00110-d780b550-785f-416c-b090-8d93694ba65c.c000.csv.crc
```

where `/tmp/out/dir=bar/part-00067-d780b550-785f-416c-b090-8d93694ba65c.c000.csv` contains

```
7
```

and `/tmp/out/dir=foo/part-00110-d780b550-785f-416c-b090-8d93694ba65c.c000.csv` contains

```
4
3
```

AFAIK it is not possible to write these output files to the same directory structure as the original input without e.g. having a customised Hadoop `FileSystem` class etc.